# SQL - group by query customization

Tags: sql

I am having a sql table contains the records as below,I want group by query 
    for the lesser Amount No present against each PropertyID and TenantID.
    For example:I want -2500 against PropertyID 1 TenantID 2.

```
PropertyID  TenantID    Amount
1              2        -6000
1              2        -2500
3              3        -15000
3              3        -10000
```

Expected Output is below

```
 PropertyID TenantID    Amount
 1             2        -2500
 3             3        -10000
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what you need?

Comment: post is modified with expected output

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
Select PropertyId, TenantID, min(Amount)
From YourTable
Group by PropertyId, TenantID
```